# Proving the existence of $f:\mathbb{Z}_2^{n} \rightarrow n$ under some conditions... iff $n=2^m$

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic, induction

I have seen a version of this somewhere and so I got interested. I will be happy to see how does mathematicians think of questions like this as to formulate an elegant proof. (I would be very happy if it will turn out as elegant as possible).
Now, lets begin with all the fun:

Let $n$ be an integer.

Consider $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+,\times)$ when $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field over elements $\{0,1\}$ with $+$ and $\times$ the addition and multiplication operations in modular-2 arithmetic respectively.

$\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ is defined to be the set $\{v=(v_0,v_1,...,v_{n-1})|\forall i < n (v_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2)\}$.

Let $i < n$ be an integer. Define $T_i:\mathbb{Z}_2^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2^{n}$ such that for each integer $j < n$ and for each $v \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$, $(T_i(v))_j = v_j+\delta_{ij}$.

For a function $F: D \rightarrow I$ and $A \subseteq I$ we define $F^{-1}(A) = \{x \in D | F(x) \in A \}$

**Prove** that there exists $f:\mathbb{Z}_2^{n} \rightarrow \{0,1,...,n-1\}$ such that for every integer $i < n$ and for every $v \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{n}$, for $W={T_i^{-1}\{v\}}$, $f|_W$ is an injection **if and only if** there exists an integer $m$ such that $n = 2^m$.

Comment: It seems you have a typo: $f:\mathbb{Z}_2^{n} \rightarrow n$.

Comment: Every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is $n=\{0,1,...,n-1\}$.
For every 2 sets $A$ and $B$ it is defined that $A^B = \{f|f:A \rightarrow B\}$.
So the set $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ is the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow n$.$\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ simply is a set of lists of size n with elements from $\mathbb{Z}_2$. and $n$ is a set of possible positions in such lists.
Therefore a function $f:\mathbb{Z}_2^n \rightarrow n$ is a function that takes a list of size n over the elements from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and returns some position.

Comment: I suggest that you add $n = \{ 0,\dots ,n-1 \}$ to your question. Moreover, $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ is the set of all functions $f : n \to  \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: I edited things, I hope this is now clearer then before.